# LINQ : Distinct and Orderby

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, distinct

I am trying to use LINQ (to EF) to get a DISTINCT list and then sort it. All the examples I found sort the result based on the DISTINCT value. But I want to sort it on a different field.

Example: Table with 2 fields (canvasSize and canvasLength);

```
var sizes = (from s in ent.competitors                         
             select s.canvasSize).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

All the examples I found give this type of answer. But it sorts by canvasSize whereas, I want to sort by canvasLength.

I'm stuck ... Any tips are greatly appreciated ...

Per J. Skeet > Additional info:

```
company  canvasSize  canvasLength

abc       8x10         8
d         8x10         8
e         10x10        10
f         10x10        10
g         40x40        40
```

I would like it to be distinct on canvasSize. The problem is that when sorted, it results in this order:

```
10x10
40x40
8x10
```

I would like the same result set but sorted using canvasLength so the result is:

```
8x10
10x10
40x40
```

Comment: Well what do you want it to be distinct *by*? It would really help if you could give some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: So, do you want both canvasSize and canvasLength in the results, sorted by canvasLength?

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? The path of least resistance is to perform your orderby on column A at the DB level, select the two columns and bring them into memory, then select your single column B and use distinct on the memory side. That's simple to write. However, it might not scale well if you have a lot of data. (This assumes that the database does not guarantee the preservation of order when using Distinct. If it does, then stick to the DB.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think what you're after may be something like this:

```
var sizes = (from s in ent.competitors                         
             select new { s.canvasSize, s.canvasLength })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x.canvasLength);
```

**Update**

Based on the extra information in your question, the following should do what you want:

```
var sizes = ent.competitors
               .Select(c => new {c.canvasSize, c.canvasLength})
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(x => x.canvasLength)
               .Select(x => x.CanvasSize)
```

Comment: For this special case when the fields depend on each other, this should work, since if `canvasSize` is identical, so is `canvasLength`. If they varied independently, it'd be a problem.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Agreed, but then you'd just add a key selector to the `Distinct()` call.

Comment: @AndrewCooper: this is almost the answer, I want only canvasSize in the result but I want the final result sorted by canvasLength

Comment: @AndrewCooper There is no key selector for `Distinct()`, at least on the standard IQueryable.

Comment: @nanonerd Just add a `.Select(x => x.canvasSize)` to the end.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Perfect !  I don't know what you guys look like in real life ... but behind the veil of stack overflow, you guys are all beautiful ... I spent hrs upon hrs researching this on my own. I post on SO and got it answered perfectly within 10 min ... thank you!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - That's true as written.  I've switched it back.  I put it at the end to anticipate a data set where the two fields are more independent.  You could put `.Distinct()` at the end if you preceed it with `.AsEnumerable` to pull the non-distinct results from the DB.

Comment: @AndrewCooper But then you can't depend on the `OrderBy` (after the `Distinct`).

Comment: @NetMage The `OrderBy()` can stay in the `IQueryable` part to execute on the server, and the .`AsEnumerable().Distinct()` will give distinct results while preserving the sort order.

Comment: @AndrewCooper The documentation for `Enumerable.Distinct` explicitly states the result is unordered. The current implementation may happen to preserve the original order, but I wouldn't write code that depended on that.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, the result is unordered, but that doesn't mean it's some random order, just that the sequence is not sorted before finding distinct values. The docs also state that the method uses deferred execution, and that nothing happens until the result sequence is enumerated.  This implies that the method is a streaming operator, and the most efficient implementation is to return distinct values as they are first encountered.  Thus the ordering of the distinct values in the source sequence is preserved.

Comment: @AndrewCooper Again, that isn't __guaranteed__. That is an implementation detail. `Distinct` could be implemented by `ToHashSet().AsEnumerable()`, and on some architectures may even be efficient, but certainly wouldn't preserve order.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sizes = ent.competitors
               .GroupBy(s => s.canvasSize)
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .OrderBy(s => s.canvasLength);
```