# Using from DataRow dRow in dt.AsEnumerable() to create a distinct ordered list in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I have the following code but am having issues with how to maintain the order:

```
var cars = (from DataRow dRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select new
                            {
                                Car = dRow["Car"],
                                CarId = dRow["CarId"],
                                CarOrder = dRow["CarOrder"]
                            }).Distinct();
```

The distinct works well but I need to preserver the CarOrder which goes from 1 to X (ascedning).

The DataTable dt have them all in order correctly but when it hits this distinct code the order does not get preserved.

I am trying to figure out how to use the OrderBy clause.

Comment: I don't get the question. You're having problems using `OrderBy()` (or the query syntax `order by`)? What's wrong? Your existing code doesn't guarantee any ordering.

Comment: How do I use OrderBy on CarOrder with Distinct? I am unsure how to use it.

Comment: You add `.OrderBy` after your Distinct call. Do you know how OrderBy works?

Comment: I need this to work }).Distinct().OrderBy("CarOrder");

Comment: I think you need to go back and learn how LINQ works. You can't pass a string argument to OrderBy. Please do some reading [on how it works](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending). You've got _double_ the reputation I've got, so this is something I'd expect from you to have done already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ : Distinct and Orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636142/linq-distinct-and-orderby)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct)

> It returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source

That means that order does not get preserved. So what you can do is probably `OrderBy()` after the `Distinct()` as following:

```
var cars = (from DataRow dRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                Car = dRow["Car"],
                CarId = dRow["CarId"],
                CarOrder = dRow["CarOrder"]
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.CarOrder);
```

See: [Does Distinct() method keep original ordering of sequence intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734852/does-distinct-method-keep-original-ordering-of-sequence-intact)